# Python where clause in for index, row in df1.iterrows():

Tags: python, where-clause

How can I do a where clause for C3? I want to do in the scenario below:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    C1 = row[2]
    C2 = row[7]
    C3 = if (row[12]) == 0 then 'blue' else 'green'
    List.append([C1, C2, C_3])
```

C3 = if (row[12]) == 0 then 'blue' else 'green' it is not working. I need something similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: That line is almost correct, but you have it in the wrong order, and `then` is not part of it.

Comment: `<true value> if <condition> else <false value>`

Comment: @IgorMoraru thanks for you comment, how can I do if I have two valuse
if (row[12]) == 0 then 'blue' 
if (row[12]) != 0 then 'red' else 'green'

Comment: I am missing red now, I want to show both blue and red if there is data if not show green

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid loops with pandas.
ex.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
C1 = df1.iloc[:, 2]     # [rows, columns]
C2 = df1.iloc[:, 7]  
C3 = numpy.where(df1.iloc[:, 12]==0, 'blue', 'green')
List = pd.concat([C1, C2, C3], axis=1)
```